# Quickblox Sample webrtc video chat not working

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, quickblox, videochat, video-conferencing

I'm trying to implement a webRTC based video chat example. I've taken a look at Quickblox and their solution. In particular, I've given their online demo a test run: http://quickblox.github.io/sample-webrtc-web/

I've opened two tabs in Chrome logged in as different users. It does not seem to work. Does this work for anyone else? Besides that, it looks like a great solution to what I'm trying to achieve so I'm hoping it is just a wrong setting with my computer.

P.S. I can see the local video stream (i.e. my own face staring back at me in the mini view, but the place where I should be able to see the remote user is black).

Comment: It works fine for me. Windows 7 x64 on Chrome 36.0.1985.143

Comment: Yes, we have some troubles with webrtc video calling now. Thanks for your feedback, we will testing it and try to find out the reason.